# Why is my image shown flipped in my contact file?

Tags: python, html, image

I have a button on my web page where people can download my contact vcf file. The problem is that whenever I click the button to download my vcf file the image is completely flipped. It only happens with photos taken from camera roll, for example if i download an image from the internet it is not being flipped.

These are the images:

[image: This image]

This image on the top is displayed correctly, but when i hit the button to download the vcf file, it shows up flipped like this:

[image]

This is part of my code in html, that shows up the image correctly:

```
<center><div class="circular"><img style="width:35%;object-fit: contain" class="rounded-circle" src="static/img/{{updated_filename}}"></div></center>

<style media="screen">
  .circular {
  border: 3px solid white;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circular img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
```

This is my python code for the vcf file:

```
def b64_image(filename):
        response = urllib.request.urlopen("static/img/" + filename)
        b64 = base64.b64encode(response.read())
        return b64.decode('utf-8')

vcf_file_path = 'static/Contacto.vcf'
with open(vcf_file_path , 'w') as file_vcard:
   vcard = vobject.vCard()
   o = vcard.add('fn')
   o.value = rowes.name
   o = vcard.add('PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=image/jpeg')
   o.type_param = 'PHOTO'
   o.value = b64_image(rowr.img_url)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly EXIF contains rotation data and only one of your viewer respects it. Try clearing all EXIF data.

Comment: @ejmin How might I go about doing that? I can`t figure out how to implement it in my function.

Comment: You could try this https://pypi.org/project/exif-delete/. I believe that deleting all EXIF data in user-uploaded images may be a very good idea to protect their privacy. EXIF contains location, camera model, date and time etc...